# How to Draw Series of Numbers in every line (cols and rows) of Grid in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, line

just wanna ask if How can I draw series of Numbers for every line of grid col and rows ...
can also be by use of label ...

something like this:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/aeblth.jpg

heres my code as for now for Grid of PictureBox:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            int numOfCells = 200;
            int cellSize = 5;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

            for (int y = 0; y < numOfCells; ++y)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, 0, y * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize, y * cellSize);
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < numOfCells; ++x)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, x * cellSize, 0, x * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize);
            }
        }
```

> Note that numbers in the bottom and right of chart Position and count
>   are depends on count and position of line of grid in picture .

thanks for the help . more power!

Comment: You could use [Microsoft chart controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of picture box.

Comment: @Junaith can you  explain more i should use that

Comment: There are plenty of article available in the web. Check [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as starter.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a block of X and Y. In the given screen shot the block of Y is about 10 and the block of X is about 2. To create the block of axes you need maximum and minimum value of graph.

**NOTE:** This is not a complete example. This is just a logic to understand how you can draw graph line.

```
int iXMin = 0;
int iXMax = 52;

int iYMin = 49890;
int iYMax = 50000;
```

Then you should create the size of block.

```
int iXSize = 26;
int iYSize = 12;

Single fXBlock = (iXMax - iXMin) / iXSize;
Single fYBlock = (iYMax - iYMin) / iYSize;
```

Now, You will require a method to convert axes position into pixel position.
This method is used to get the point of axes.

```
Single fXPxlSize = (pic.ClientRectangle.Width / (iXMax-iXMin))); //Getting X pixle size between two value.
Single fYPxlSize = (pic.ClientRectangle.Height / (iYMax-iYMin)); //Getting Y pixle size between two value.
```

Now, You can point out the value in the PictureBox.
Suppose you have first value `XValue=0,YValue=50000` then you can get pixel position by using following formula.

```
int iX = Convert.ToInt32((XValue - XMin) * fXPxlSize);
int iY = Convert.ToInt32((YValue - YMin) * fYPxlSize);
Point p = New Point(iX,iY);
```

Create two List then add all those points one by one into the list. First is used to draw Cyan Line and Second is used to draw Yellow Line

```
List<Point> lstPointsC = new List<Point>();  //Declaration should be class level.
List<Point> lstPointsY = new List<Point>();  //Declaration should be class level.

lstPointsC.Add(p);
if (lstPointsY.Count > 0)
    lstPointsY.Add(new Point(iX, lstPointsY[lstPointsY.Count].Y));
lstPointsB.Add(p);
```

Create code for Lines.

```
Graphics g = pic.CreateGraphics(); //you can also use e.Graphics from pic_paint event.
g.DrawLines(Pens.Cyan, lstPointsC.ToArray());
g.DrawLines(Pens.Yellow, lstPointsY.ToArray());
```

This method is used to draw custom line graph in your own control or form. But, I would like to suggest you use any third party tool like **Crystal Report** or **Devexpress Charts**.